# How to change a word smoothly on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

how is it possible to change a word smoothly when hovering?

**Example**
[This effect, but only on hover](http://themes.pixelwars.org/photographer/)

**Code**

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Link 01<span>Link 01 altertext</span></li>
    <li>Link 02<span>Link 03 altertext</span></li>
    <li>Link 03<span>Link 03 altertext</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li span{
    display:none;
}
```

It should be a Navigation. Only the word in the `<li>` should change with its `<span>`. On mouse-out the `<span>` should be hide again.

Comment: post your code jsfiddle link or something

Comment: Do not post only JSFiddle links, instead [edit] your question and include the code in the question itself, if you have any of your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<span class="words">
  <span>Link 01</span>
  <span>Link 02</span>
  <span>Link 03</span>
</span>
```

JS:

```
var $words = $('.words'),
    interval = 2000,
    nextWord = 0;

$words.each(function(index, element) {
  var $elem = $(element),
      $spans = $elem.find("span");

  $spans.eq(0).addClass('active');

  var animateFunc = function(){
    nextWord = $elem.find('.active').next().length ? $elem.find('.active').next().index() : 0;
    $elem.find('.active').addClass('fade-out').removeClass('fade-in active');
    $spans.eq(nextWord).addClass('fade-in active').removeClass('fade-out');
  };

  setInterval(animateFunc,interval);
});
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/16954/

Comment: Its nice, but not what im looking for. It should be a navigation. So only the <li> should change with its <span> and on mouse-Out the <span> should be hidde again.